# ASP .NET MVC - Getting object template string result out of a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am re-opening my question as it has been set as duplicate while it is not - or people who tagged it as duplicate should explain me why it is a duplicate..........
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227988/html-displayfor-result

How can I get the result of the method Html.DisplayFor() in a C# Class, like in a View model or even in a Controller ? And not in the View Aspx or Razor.

[Edit]
In fact I have a table to display and depending on the number of record I use a Telerik table or a simple HTLM table.

For the moment I have a function in my view to get the string to display for each column so I use the same format for both tables.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<ViewModels.OrderViewModel>" %>

<script runat="server" type="text/C#">

public string GetCellValue (String columnName, Order order)
{
        string value = "";
        switch (columnName)
        {
            case "Ref":
                value = order.order.Reference.ToString(); break;
            case "Etc":
                value = Html.DisplayFor(p => order.order.Etc).ToHtmlString();break;             
            case "Payment date": 
                foreach (Executions ex in order.executions)
                {
                    value += ex.Date.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " ";
                }
                break;
```

I want to move this function out of my view in the ViewModel for example, but I do not know how I can call the function Html.DisplayFor() out of a view.

Comment: this question is clear, your last one was not.

Comment: could you post your code here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't understand why would you want to do it, but...

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

class Example {    

    void Method()
    {
       HtmlHelper<TModel> Html = new HtmlHelper<TModel>();
       MvcHtmlString result = Html.DisplayFor(prop => Model.Prop);
    }
}
```

After your edit, if you move GetCellValue to another place, maybe you will only need to do

```
       MvcHtmlString result = new MvcHtmlString(order.order.Etc);
```

as, it should only display its value as string (unless you have set up a template for it).

Comment: It does not seem to work using ASP .NET MVC 3, method DisplayFor is not available.

Comment: I can't check it right now, because I don't have Mvc 3 installed at work (and don't have install privileges), but I'll edit my answer with other way.

Comment: Unfortunately Etc is an Entity Object, and the constructor of MvcHtmlString is asking for a string so it does not work.